# Is there a SQL command to return a count of an item with a WHERE and then the overall total?

Tags: sql

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(partNumber) as count, partNumber
FROM CONNOR_TRACKER
WHERE warrantyDate > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
GROUP BY partNumber
```

This returns me:

```
PART0001,543
```

How can I also return the total count of this part?

My goal is to create a table like this:

```
Part Number,In Warranty,Total
PART0001,543,10000
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SUM case statement will do the trick:

```
SELECT 
partNumber
COUNT(partNumber) as Total,
SUM ( CASE WHEN  warrantyDate > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Inwarranty
FROM CONNOR_TRACKER
GROUP BY partNumber
```

Comment: If you like the answer could you please accept the solution. I need to catch-up Gordon somehow!

Comment: the battle is on! good luck on catching him :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT partNumber,
       COUNT(partNumber) as total_count, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN warrantyDate > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as future_count
FROM CONNOR_TRACKER 
GROUP BY partNumber;
```

Note that the filtering has moved to the `SUM()` expression from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: absolutely rapid and spot on ... thank you very much

Comment: @MartynBell . . . So much for having the first correct answer.